# Cannot log into windows 10 computer

Tags: windows-10, microsoft-account

first of all I'm new so I apologize if I am breaking any rules in this thread.

Now here's my problem. I am a very active user of my pc. I used to login each and every day with the same password, which I entered hundreds of times. However, a few weeks ago I was unable to login. My password was changed.

Normally you would just use the 'forgotten password' button, which I did. It turns out however, that I no longer have access to the email my Microsoft account is registered under. So I did the checklist of personal questions, but after weeks of failures I have pretty much given up hope.

I tried asking for help on the Microsoft website, but you had to register for help. Not much use there. By now I'm willing to register a new account to my pc, but please if any of you have a better idea that might help, it's welcome. I'm willing to try anything at this point.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Hi Jasper, welcome to Super User. What's your question here?

Comment: Do you only have the one account to access the PC?

Answer (score 0):

If It shows "Something went wrong" error, then the issue is your user profile is corrupted, then you have to create a new user account and later link it to Microsoft account.

Otherwise some common fixes are that:

- temporarily login with the other administrator local account or using password not PIN
- disable all antivirus software
- check if the group policy setting
  Computer Configuration > Windows settings > Security > Settings > Local Policies > Security Options > Accounts: Block Microsoft Accounts is set to Block on secpol.msc, and if then enable it

after doing these, log out and try to re-login using the Microsoft account

HTH